# Dynamic array of int pointers causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I found a segmentation fault in my C code and could not find a good explanation or solution for it after searching.

This first code gives me segmentation fault after printing 0.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int **defs = malloc(16 * sizeof *defs);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        *defs[i] = i;
    }
    free(defs);
    return 0;
}
```

This second code works fine.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int *defs = malloc(16 * sizeof defs);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        defs[i] = i;
    }
    free(defs);
    return 0;
}
```

These are just examples, not my actual code. I also tried doing pointer arithmetic but same result.
Could someone please explain this? Thank you.

Comment: `*defs[i]`.  Before doing that, you need to initialize`defs[i]` to point somewhere.

Comment: Pointers must point somewhere before being dereferenced

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In first code you have not allocated each of the `int*` memory blocks.
So, before assigning values to `defs[i]`, you have to populate it with memory of type `int*`.

```
defs[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * number_of_elements);
```

And then `defs[i][some_index] = value`.

Comment: In my case, adding `def[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));` in the loop worked. Thanks.

Comment: your `def[i]` can only store 1 element....But you can store more than 1 element. But what you should always avoid....segmentation fault can occur.

Comment: @Munir ...um. Why are you allocating individual `int`s on the heap, exactly? Why are you even creating an array of pointers instead of an array of `int`s, and why are you using `malloc` instead of `new`?

Comment: @KyleStrand I don't know the initial size of the array. So I can't do it on the stack. I need the array of pointers because in my program, the data is read from a file and shared across the program. Also, this is C, not C++. So there is no `new` or `delete`, only `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: @Munir Ah, could have sworn I saw you including `iostream`--sorry. But I don't understand what the relationship is between (1) keeping *pointers* rather than raw `int`s in your array, (2) reading data from a file, and (3) sharing data throughout the program. Those three issues seem entirely unrelated.